# If (3,0) is a critical point, find if f(x,y) is a local maxima, local minima or a saddle point at (3,0)

Tags: calculus, functions

So i have this function:$f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-4y^3+x^2-33x$

Partials derivatives in $x$,$xx$,$y$,$yy$ and $xy$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=3x^2+3y^2+2x-33$

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}=6x+2$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}=6xy-12y^2=6y(x-2y)$

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}=6x-24y$

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x\partial y}=6y$

So i have this for the point $(3,0)$

$\Delta (3,0)=36x^2-144xy+12x-48y=360$

So the point $(3,0)$ is a saddle point.

Am i correct here? If not where did i go wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions for the partial derivatives are correct, and so is the determinant

$$D(x,y)=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2=(20)(18)-0^2=360$$

while $f_{xx}=20$

#### Second Partial Derivative Test

Since $D(x,y)>0$, the point is a local min *or* max; since $f_{xx}>0$ the point $(3,0)$ is a local *minimum*, rather than a saddle point. If we had instead $D(x,y)<0$ then the point would have been a saddle point.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of the system
$$
\begin{cases}
3x^2+3y^2+2x-33=0,\\
6y(x-2y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
are:
$$(3,\,0),\;\;\left(-\frac{11}{3},\;0 \right) ,\\ \left(- \frac{4}{15} - \frac{2\cdot \sqrt{499}}{15}, \; - \frac{2}{15} - \frac{\sqrt{499}}{15}\right),\;\; \left(- \frac{4}{15} + \frac{2\cdot \sqrt{499}}{15}, \; - \frac{2}{15} + \frac{\sqrt{499}}{15}\right).$$